# Black Israelites: who is responsible for deicide?

Tags: anti-semitism

I am extremely interested in the answer to this but I realize this may not be the right place to ask it and would happily post it elsewhere.

When I mention Black Israelites I mean them or other groups who assert that Blacks are the actual Jews and non-Blacks who claim to be Jews, Ashkenazim I think they have in mind, are descendants of Khazars.

I do not know if deicide (the claim that Jews murdered Christ) is part of the Black Israelite/Black Hebrew doctrine but I know for sure that Farrakhan both accuses Jews of deicide but also calls them "so-called Jews".

So it's very simple: Does anyone who asserts that Jews are in some sense false Jews and yet asserts that Jews are responsible for deicide claim that it was these false Jews, who in every other respect are not really Jews, nonetheless were present in the land where Jesus was crucified to cause his execution?

Do Black Hebrews (and similar groups) claim that their ancestors (in a major lapse I suppose) killed Christ or is this simple question something they don't discuss?

Comment: This is not the right place for questions about Black Israelite beliefs.

Comment: This isn't about Judaism

Comment: @dude: there is an antisemitism tag and the question is indeed about antisemitism, but as I said, if there is a better place that is recommended I will ask it there.

Comment: That tag is for questions about Judaism that touch on the topic of antisemitism. This isn't a question about (normative) Judaism.

Comment: @shmosel: okay: again, perhaps u can suggest a better place? I think antisemitism is an important aspect of Judaism -- I see a question about the spanish expulsion: that is purely about antisemitism, not about Jewish beliefs/practices.

Comment: I agree that that this is off-topic. As a side-note, I've tried to reason with BHIs online in the past. Their theology and theories of alt-history aren't very well-developed. As a collective, they haven't thought enough about the vast number of discrepancies in their beliefs.

Comment: @harel13: That may basically answer the question. People who believe in history based on someone's dream or vision may not be too concerned about consistency. Where should this question be asked? why is the spanish expulsion on topic? history SE will certainly say this question is not on-topic either. A religion SE might be right.

Comment: The Spanish Expulsion is an event that is directly tied to Jews. What you're asking is a question about an internal discrepancy in a very much non-Jewish group. Your question might be relevant in one of the following groups: History or Christianity, although both might have their own reasons for thinking it off-topic. There isn't a general theology/religion SE to my knowledge.

Comment: @Harel13: i would ask if this question came up in your discussions with BIs -- History for sure won't work and Christianity is technically way off. So as a personal request, I ask this question of u about ur discussions.

Comment: No, it never occurred to me. It's certainly creative, but unfortunately I don't think any of their answers would be interesting. They typically try to deflect because they don't seem to have answers.

Comment: @harel13 one very interesting thing that shows either the complexity or inconsistency of the BI/BH (I forget who specifically) is the recent street fight: pali-supporters vs BI/BH. I suggest that the pali side saw the mogen david and attacked. Or maybe BI are zionists but only for blacks, not "white jews" nor even palestinians. wow, what screwed up world we live in.

Comment: @releseabe what's crazy about "this" world? Arrogance has always existed